# how to knit an R Markdown file to pdf

Tags: r, r-markdown, knitr, tinytex

When I try to render an R Markdown file to pdf, I get the following error:

> /Applications/RStudio.app/Contents/MacOS/pandoc/pandoc +RTS -K512m -RTS PC_final_proj.utf8.md --to latex --from markdown+autolink_bare_uris+ascii_identifiers+tex_math_single_backslash --output PC_final_proj.tex --template /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.6/Resources/library/rmarkdown/rmd/latex/default-1.17.0.2.tex --highlight-style tango --pdf-engine pdflatex --variable graphics=yes --variable 'geometry:margin=1in' --variable 'compact-title:yes' --include-in-header /var/folders/95/jvthp8r158q50jv8qjwy75j80000gn/T//RtmpIPFCYS/rmarkdown-str66203f066768.html 
>   output file: PC_final_proj.knit.md

! Package inputenc Error: Unicode character  (U+1F60E)
(inputenc)                not set up for use with LaTeX.

Try other LaTeX engines instead (e.g., xelatex) if you are using pdflatex. For R Markdown users, see [this](https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown/pdf-document.html)

> Error: Failed to compile PLSC_final_proj.tex. See https://yihui.name/tinytex/r/#debugging for debugging tips. See PLSC_final_proj.log for more info.
>   Execution halted

I have tried the following to resolve the issue but I cannot work around it;

```
{r message=FALSE}
```

in all the r chunks, and, changed the line latex_engine: xelatex to the YAML header

```
title: "Document 6"
output:
   pdf_document:
        latex_engine: xelatex
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Did you enable installing missing packages on the fly? Or manually configuring `inputenc`? See [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/83440/inputenc-error-unicode-char-u8-not-set-up-for-use-with-latex)

Comment: Try running `tinytex::install_tinytex()`, then close RStudio, re-open it and knit again.

Comment: I tried running  tinytex::install_tinytex() but I'm still getting the same error

Comment: Please post a [mre] so that we can test possible solutions with your actual code.